# Arranging Text next to div based on available space

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, alignment

#### Goal:

Currently building a chart in React trying to show available time within a time period. The chart is filled with items that have time and name.
I want to dynamically arrange text (name) next to div (time) if there is space available.
The goal is to have a chart with bars where the bars are next to each other each in a new line, with the name of the item next to it.

In the end, it should look something like this:

```
-- Item 1
  ---- Item 2
      ----- Item 3
           --- Item 4
              -- Item 5
                ---- Item 6
```

The chart can get to the maximum length of the parent container. Therefore it can happen that there is no space next to the bar. In this case, I would like to display the text on the left side of the bar. This should happen so the bars still "touch" each other meaning the text is left to where the bar would be if it was to the right.

Final Example:

```
Container:
____________________________
|  -- Item 1               |                     
|    ---- Item 2           |
|        ----- Item 3      |
|              --- Item 4  |
|          Item 5 --       |
|             Item 6 ----  |
____________________________
```

#### Problem:

My code is already displaying the blocks correctly. The problem I have is that the text pushes all of it (including the bar) to the right so it no longer aligns with the bar above.

```
____________________________
|  -- Item 1               |                     
|    ---- Item 2           |
|        ----- Item 3      |
|              --- Item 4  |
|                  Item 5 --       
|                    Item 6 ----  
____________________________
```

#### Code:

```
{
  flatArray.map((p, index) => {
    usedWidth += p.width;
    if (usedWidth < totalWidth / 2) {
      return (
        <Grid
          container
          direction="column"
          alignItems="center"
          style={{ marginTop: 30 * index, width: p.width, height: 30 }}
        >
          <div
            style={{
              backgroundColor: p.color,
              width: p.width,
              height: 30
            }}
          />
          <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
            <Typography variant="body1" noWrap style={{ marginLeft: 10 }}>
              {p.title}
            </Typography>
          </div>
        </Grid>
      );
    }
    return (
      <Grid
        container
        direction="column"
        alignItems="center"
        style={{ marginTop: 30 * index, width: p.width, height: 30 }}
      >
        <div style={{ display: "flex", float: "left" }}>
          <Typography variant="body1" noWrap>
            {p.title}
          </Typography>
        </div>
        <div
          style={{
            backgroundColor: p.color,
            width: p.width,
            height: 30
          }}
        />
      </Grid>
    );
  });
}
```

Also right now I just look if the bar with would extend over half the total as I could not figure out a way to see if there is enough space for the text left.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
var a = document.getElementById("menu");
var px=0;
var cDiv = a.children;
for (var i = 0; i < cDiv.length; i++) {
    if (cDiv[i].tagName == "LI") {   //or use toUpperCase()
    px = px +20;
    cDiv[i].style.marginLeft = px+'px';  //do styling here
    }
}
```

```css
.menu{
  list-style-type : none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu" id="menu">
  <li>----Tea</li>
  <li>----Coffee</li>
  <li>----Boost</li>
  <li>----Horlicks</li>
  <li>----Green Tea</li>
</ul>
```